# Pasar un dato TEXT a FLOAT en CQL

Tags: base-de-datos, cassandra

Tengo en Cassandra una columna que tiene el formato `TEXT`, aunque en verdad lo que almacena son números (por ejemplo `12.23`) y necesito hacer una `SELECT` en CQL para comparar si es mayor a un determinado número.

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT temperatura from db.estaciones WHERE temperatura > 23.31
```

El problema es que no sé como hacer que compare un `TEXT` con un `FLOAT`.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Por favor mira en la ayuda [ask] , [qué puedo preguntar](/help/on-topic) y [qué no](/help/dont-ask). Independientemente que pueda ser un tema de este foro, NO debes duplicar tus propias preguntas, si no realizarlas correctamente. añadiendo la máxima información que puedas, poniendo el código que has intentado y aportar [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Perdona, soy nuevo en esto, ¿entonces la pregunta está bloqueada? Es que en la anterior me equivoque y entonces la borre? ¿Qué debo hacer?

Comment: @J.Salguero no te preocupes. Ya la borraste y tienes una nueva. A futuro, considera que hay una opción [edit] al pie de cada publicación (preguntas y respuestas). Al seleccionarla, puedes modificar la información de la misma p.e. traducir texto a español, agregar más información, agregar imágenes o enlaces, entre otras cosas.

Comment: Puesto que eres nuevo en el sitio, te recomiendo primero visitar el [tour] y luego [ask]. Esas son las herramientas mínimas para poder publicar buenas preguntas en el sitio.

Answer (score 1):

Hola con Cassandra puedes hacer esto:

```
    SELECT Cast(temperatura as float)
    FROM   db.estaciones
    WHERE  Cast(temperatura as float) > 23.31
```

Espero te sirva Saludos.